# Why doesn't TeXstudio produce {} for my custom commands?

Tags: macros, texstudio

I'm having the following problem in TeXstudio 2.7.0. I have a template where I've  declared some custom commands, such as

```
\newcommand{\myAnswer}[1]{ \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]  \item[\textbf{Lösung: }]~#1 \end{itemize}}
```

Now, when I type `\myAnwser`, Texstudio doesn't produce the `{}` for the parameter, altough it does for LaTeX commands, such as `\textit{}`.

I don't know what is wrong, because it used to work on my old PC (on which I had TeXstudio 2.6.6 installed). Does that problem have to do with the version of TeXstudio I'm using (2.7.0)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: ok thanks for the information and the formatting.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you referring to TeXstudio's autocompletion feature?

Comment: This should help: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_does_a_command_not_show_up_in_the_completion.3F

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/936/) in version 2.7.0.

Will be fixed in the next release. If you are on windows, you may try the [latest development snapshot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%20SVN/texstudio271_snapshot_2014-03-26_win.exe/download), but beware it's not a stable release.